# How to split string using jquery/java script with output as "1,2,222,FF-GA"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to split `String` "," seperated to give out put as "1,2,222,FF-GA using below method

```
var nav = "1-2-222-FF-GA"; 
var arry = str.split('-');

$.each(arry,function(num,nav){
    console.log(nav); 
});
```

**Output:**

```
1,2,222,FF-GA
```

Please help me out to fetch string in above output format.

Comment: You can get a better answer if you can explain the condition or logic if you want to replace all the `-` with `,` or something else since in your question you have left out a `-` do you want to preserve the `-` if inbetween alphabets and replace with `,` if inbetween numbers or something else all together

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** and **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** with regex

```js
var nav = "1-2-222-FF-GA";
nav = nav.match(/\d+|([a-z]+-)*[a-z]+/gi).join();

document.write(nav);
```

It will match digits or `-` separated alphabets

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/bE0cE6/1)**

```
\d+|([a-z]+-)*[a-z]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xsyYz2aB1JRro4GA)

Comment: `nav.match(/\d+|(\w+-)*\w+/gi).join(',');`